# Limited require() inside VM

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to make a limited require in wich files require()'d by VM programs are also run inside the VM?

Is it safe to pass a function to the script wich reads a file and then it returns it a VM instance of the code.

My situation is that I need a sandboxed file that is kind-of trusted to start up the enviroment by requiring all the other files. This should not be done by passing them in context because those files have to be required when the file wants, since those required files might change.
The required files are not really trusted, so normal require() is dangerous. As only way code has to mess up is that.

So: init.js calls files/core1.js, files/core2.js and files/whatever_it_wants.js

What I use:

```
var sandbox = {
 fs: vfs,
 write: console.log,
 files: f,
 exit: process.exit
}
var context = new vm.createContext(sandbox);
var script = new vm.Script(fs.readFileSync("./e/master.js"),{timeout: 10000});
script.runInContext(context);
```

master.js needs to load files that are not very trustable, having files (contains all files available) and it's virtual filesystem for it to do its FS operations, and write/exit to do what it needs.

Comment: `require()` from a VM program will execute in the VM.  There's only one execution context per node.js process (unless you explicitly start other processes) so if you load node.js into a VM and then `require()` some modules into that, they will be in the VM.

Comment: The issue is that real require() will allow kind-of exiting the sandbox by requiring child_process and execute shell commands, breaking the VM.

Comment: If that's the issue you're concerned about, then please add that to your question.  If you're talking about running untrusted scripts on the server that may attempt malicious things, that's a very messy security problem and a lot has been written about that issue before.  I'd suggest some searching and reading.

Comment: I already added to question why I cant just use require(). I have read that since code has no require() its only danger is with infinite loops, that can be fixed with timeout, all in a new process.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot tell what you're really asking from reading your question.  Maybe if you showed some code and explained where in the code what your question is?

Comment: @jfriend00, I edited it, now it contains what I currently use. The question is, how to require files from the master.js?

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem?  master.js can load whatever you tell it to.  What exactly are you trying to protect against?

Comment: @jfriend00 I think iovoid is trying to say that they are worried about if an attacker were to require something like the `child_proccess` module and they ran a malicious command, they are worried that that could cause harm outside the VM. But I think you address that briefly in your first comment.

Comment: @iovoid Are you worried that someone will require a file and then have access to the host's filesystem?

Comment: Why not just create your own `require()` wrapper that whitelists what you need?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my first comment, the issue is that normal require could load harmful features of core modules. As node's VM documentation says: _The require() in the above case shares the state with context it is passed from. This may introduce risks when untrusted code is executed, e.g. altering objects from the calling thread's context in unwanted ways._ So, **I need to not let child files tamper with the main thing, nor load harmful core modules**.